# conversion from 'QSqlQuery*' to non-scalar type 'QSqlQuery' requested QT Creator

Tags: c++, sql, qt

hey guys i m trying to fill a TableView on QT creator i tried to use this code but i got a weird error

conversion from 'QSqlQuery*' to non-scalar type 'QSqlQuery' requested

```
void FillTable(){
MainWindow conn;//this is a variable type MainWindow
QSqlQueryModel * modal=new QSqlQueryModel();//Creating the Modal
conn.connOpen();//connOpen Method to Open the Connection
QSqlQuery sql=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);//MyDb MyDatabase declarted in connOpen
sql->prepare("Select * from particulier");
sql->exec();
modal->setQuery(sql);
ui->tableViewUi->setModel(modal);
conn.connClose();


}
```

connOpen

```
bool connOpen(){
        mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        mydb.setHostName("Localhost");
        mydb.setDatabaseName("testnaltis");
        mydb.setUserName("root");
        mydb.setPassword("");
        mydb.open();
        //bool ok = db.open();
        if(mydb.isOpen()){
            qDebug()<<("Connexion Etablie");
            return true;
        }else{
            qDebug()<<("Erreur De connexion");
             return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QSqlQuery sql=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
```

has mismatching type and should be

```
// C++11
auto sql=new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
// or
// C++98
QSqlQuery * sql = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
```

Also,

```
modal->setQuery(sql);
```

should be

```
modal->setQuery(*sql);
```

since it expects an object, not a pointer to an object.

Comment: What About this 
 'ui' was not declared in this scope
 ui->tableViewUi->setModel(modal);
 ^

Comment: @Samer Sorry, we can't debug the code we can't see.